# Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching nav in div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using [next.js](https://nextjs.org/) and I get the following error: "Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching nav in div".

Here is my code:

```
export default function Member() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const {
    isAuthenticated,
    authState,
    profileState
  } = useContext(AuthContext);
  let profileArray = profileState.savedProfile;

  const redirect = () => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      router.push("/");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {!isAuthenticated() ? (
        redirect()
      ) : (
        <>
          <Navigation />
          <main className="main">
            {{ /* Code that uses let profileArray */ }}
          </main>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

I think the error occurs because of the `React.Fragment` - because when I replace the React.Fragments with f.ex. div, I get a different error "Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching div in div".

I just don't know how to solve this issue. I already tried to use `useEffect`, but then I get a server error.

Any suggestions? I'm new to next.js, so any help with code improvement is appreciated! Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**
A similar error occurs on other pages - only the warning differs f.ex. "Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching div in button". I think this is related to the **AvatarDropdown**, which is part of the **Navigation**. The code:

```
const AvatarDropdown = () => {
  const node = useRef();
  const { authState, isAuthenticated, logout } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  const member = () => {
    router.push("/member");
  };
  
  const dropdownItems = [
    { title: "My Account", onClick: () => member() },
    {title: "Log Out", onClick: logout},
  ];

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (node.current && !node.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setDropdownOpen(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClick);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={node}>
      {isAuthenticated() ? (
        <button
          onClick={() => setDropdownOpen(!dropdownOpen)}
        >
          <div>
            <p>{authState.name}</p>
            <ExpandMoreIcon />
          </div>
        </button>
      ) : (
        <Link href="/login">
          <button>
            <p>LOGIN</p>
          </button>
        </Link>
      )}

      {dropdownOpen && (
        <div>
          <DropdownContent dropdownItems={dropdownItems} />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: The code that you have written looks correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So do you have any suggestions what I could look for to solve the error?

Answer (score 3):

`redirect` does not return any html node.  Any side effect code should be executed in `useEffect` hook.

This is recommended. Try this..

```
export default function Member() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const {
    isAuthenticated,
    authState,
    profileState
  } = useContext(AuthContext);
  let profileArray = profileState.savedProfile

  React.useEffect(()=> {
    if(!isAuthenticated()){
     router.push('/')
    }
  },[])

  if(!isAuthenticated()){
   return <p>Loading..</p>
  }
 
  return ( 
   <>
          <Navigation / >
          <main className = "main">
            //code that uses let profileArray
          </main>
         </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So for the first render I get the text "Loading..." and - depending on isAuthenticated - user gets redirected or not. This is a side "check"/effect and that's why we're using useEffect, right? The code works. Only when I refresh the page the error is still there.

Comment: yes. does it work first time only? on refresh you get error?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with nav?

Comment: i am not sure about that issue.. would like to see `Navigation` component

Comment: I've added some code from the nav that is relevant, I think -> see edits

Answer (score 0):

U can use Redirect component from 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: I'm using next.js (ssr). So I think there would be issues.